# expected ')' before '*' token passing in Node

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I've searched this question and the previous ones do not seem to be related to my problem. I seem to have a disconnect on passing a node into a function, for some reason I keep getting this error when attempting to compile.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char c;
    int titleCount;
    int authorCount;
    char bookTitle[35];
    char author[35];

    /* Create Struct */
    typedef struct bookData {
        char bookTitle[35];
        char author[35];
        int book_stock;
        float retail_price;
        int wholesale_purchased;
        int customer_purchased;
        struct bookData *book;
    } new_book;

    /*Create Node */

    typedef struct Node {
        new_book books;
        struct Node *next;
    } node_t;

    /* We are GUARANTEED at least 1 input value, so go ahead and initialize the head */

    node_t *head = NULL; /*Initalize head to NULL since it is empty */
    head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if(head == NULL) {
        printf("allocation failed");
        return 0;
    }
    head -> next = NULL;
    /*Memory allocation successful */

    /*Might as well populate the head with data from the user */

    titleCount = 0;
    authorCount = 0;

    printf("Enter Title\n");
    while(( c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        bookTitle[titleCount++] = c;

    }
    bookTitle[titleCount] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", bookTitle);
    strcpy(head -> books.bookTitle, bookTitle);

    printf("Enter Author\n");
    while(( c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        author[authorCount++] = c;
    }
    author[authorCount] = '\0';
    strcpy(head -> books.author, author);

    printf("Bookstock #:\n");
    scanf("%d", &(head -> books).book_stock);

    printf("Enter retail price $:\n");
    scanf("%f", &(head -> books).retail_price);

    printf("Enter Wholesale purchased quanity:\n");
    scanf("%d", &(head  -> books).wholesale_purchased);

    printf("Enter quantity sold:\n");
    scanf("%d", &(head -> books).customer_purchased);

    printf("%s\n", head -> books.bookTitle);

    printf("%s\n", head -> books.author);

    printf("%d\n", head -> books.book_stock);

    printf("%.2f\n", head -> books.retail_price);

    printf("%d\n", head -> books.wholesale_purchased);

    printf("%d\n", head -> books.customer_purchased);

    takeUserInput(head);
}

/*Now populate all other nodes, until user enters END_DATA */

void takeUserInput(node **head) {
    int titleCount;
    int authorCount;
    char bookTitle[35];
    char author[35];

    int flag = 0;

    while(1) {
        titleCount = 0;
        authorCount = 0;
        node_t *temp = NULL;
        temp = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        temp -> next = NULL;
        printf("Enter Title\n");
        while(( c = getchar()) != '\n') {
            bookTitle[titleCount++] = c;
        }
        bookTitle[titleCount] = '\0'
        if(bookTitle == "END_DATA") {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        strcpy(temp -> books.bookTitle, bookTitle);

        printf("Enter Author\n");
        while(( c = getchar()) != '\n') {
            author[authorCount++] = c;
        }
        author[authorCount++] = '\0';
        strcpy(temp -> books.author, author);


        printf("Bookstock #\n");
        scanf("%d", &(temp - > books).book_stock);

        printf("Enter retail Price in $\n:");
        scanf("%.2f", &(temp -> books).retail_price);

        printf("Enter wholesale purchased\n:");
        scanf("%d", &(temp -> books).wholesale_purchased);

        printf("Enter customer purchased\n:");
        scanf("%d", &(temp -> books).customer_purchased);

        if(temp -> books.book_stock < head -> books.book_stock) {
            void pushToFront(head, temp);
        } else {
            void insert(head,temp);
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1) {
        free(temp);
    }

}

void pushToFront(node_t **head, node_t *temp) {
    temp -> next = *head;
    *head -> temp;
}

void insert(node_t *head, node_t *temp) {
    node_t *current = head;
    while(current -> next -> new_book.book_stock  < temp -> new_book.book_stock || current -> != NULL) {
        current = current -> next;
    }
    if(current -> next = NULL) {
        current -> next = temp;
    }
    node_t *xtraNode = current -> next
                       current -> next = temp;
    temp -> next = xtraNode;
}
```

Error:

```
lab3p1.c:114: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
lab3p1.c:180: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
lab3p1.c:188: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
```

To my understanding, I only need to pass in a double pointer when I'm adjusting which node the head points to `pushToFront`. So on `insert()`, I'm not actually adjusting the head pointer, just the `next pointer` of a particular node and the node being inserted. So I'm a little confused as to why this error is occurring.

Comment: please indent your code properly, you might even find the syntax error (probably a missing semicolon) by doing that.

Comment: First, you need to define your structs in global space. Second, you `typdef` it as `node_t`, but try to declare `void takeUserInput(node **head){`. See: [where to declare structures, inside main() or outside main()?](//stackoverflow.com/q/31380268)

Comment: Line 114 is `int flag = 0;`

Comment: `node_t *xtraNode = current -> next` (near the end of file) is missing a semicolon.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, one constraint I have is that I can not declare any global variables

Comment: @Kyle I am referring to where you define your structs. That's different than creating a variable. Please read the link I posted.

Comment: @Kyle you *must* have the `struct` type declaration outside of `main` otherwise you won't be able to write functions that take an argument of that type.

Comment: @WeatherVane both my structures? The Node itself and the structure defined inside the node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spent a bit time to try compile your code but the number of errors is astonishing. Your code requires your serious attention.

Start with the simple things first.
First move the declaration of the structures before `main`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Create Struct */
typedef struct bookData{
    char bookTitle[35];
    char author[35];
    int book_stock;
    float retail_price;
    int wholesale_purchased;
    int customer_purchased;
    struct bookData *book;
}new_book;

/*Create Node */

typedef struct Node{
    new_book books;
    struct Node *next;
}node_t;

void takeUserInput(node_t **head);
void pushToFront(node_t **head, node_t *temp);
void insert(node_t *head, node_t *temp);

int main(){
 //...
}
```

and put your function prototypes before `main` as well.

```
void takeUserInput(node **head){
```

should be:

```
   void takeUserInput(node_t **head){
```

and

```
   takeUserInput(head);
```

should be:

```
   takeUserInput(&head);
```

and

```
void takeUserInput(node_t **head){ // node_t not node sg7
    int titleCount;
    int authorCount;
    char bookTitle[35];
    char author[35];
    int c;       // declaration was missing sg7!
```

later

```
bookTitle[titleCount] = '\0'   // missing ;
if(bookTitle == "END_DATA"){   // this is NOT the way to compare strings
```

I also noticed that you have not accepted a single answer, yet.

I have stopped here and I let you continue yourself. Good luck. Everyone has to carry his own cross.

Comment: Thanks, biggest problem was structure definition. I solved it shortly after that

Comment: @Kyle Great! I am glad to hear that!